# Get the current activity to handle NFC TAG discovered

Tags: java, android, nfc

I've got an android app with several activities. I want the current activity to handle the nfc discovered event, as the state of the app determines what i want to do with the tag

As can be seen in the attached code i've set up the intents on each activity and implemented the onResume, onPause and onNewIntent methods in each activty.

Yet, for some reason the MainActivty is the only one which gets called even though one of the other activities is the active one. Eg. it is the one with the current GUI.

You guys have any idea how to get the active activity to handle the NFC discovered?

Any help greatly appreciated :)

Here is the ApplicationManifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <activity
        android:name=".ConfigureStableNamesActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED " />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="www.nxp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/products/identification_and_security/smart_label_and_tag_ics/ntag/series/NT3H1101_NT3H1201.html"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <!-- <action android:name="android.nfc.action.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED"/>-->
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED " />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="www.nxp.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/products/identification_and_security/smart_label_and_tag_ics/ntag/series/NT3H1101_NT3H1201.html"
                android:scheme="http" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

In each of my activities i have this code to handle the NFC discovered intent

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    ntagHandler.start();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ntagHandler.stop();
}

@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
        nfcHandler = new NearFieldCommunicationHandler(tag);
        nfcHandler.connect();

        // DO SOMETHING HERE
        // dataModel.readStableNames(nfcHandler);
    } catch(IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Caught exception: " + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement "The foreground dispatch system". it allows an activity to intercept an intent and claim priority over other activities. Please refer: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/advanced-nfc#java

> First create pendingIntent globally in your each activities as below:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

> then take IntentFilter globally and init with null as below:

```
IntentFilter[] intentFiltersArray = null;

Write below code in onCreate() method:

IntentFilter ndef = new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED);
        try {
            ndef.addDataType("*/*");    /* YOU CAN TYPE HERE EITHER android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED or
            android.nfc.action.ACTION_TAG_DISCOVERED */
        }
        catch (IntentFilter.MalformedMimeTypeException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("fail", e);
        }
        IntentFilter[] intentFiltersArray = new IntentFilter[] {ndef, };
```

> then take techListsArray globally as below:

```
String[][] techListsArray = new String[][] { new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() } };
```

Finally write below code to enable and disable the foreground dispatch when the activity loses (onPause()) and regains (onResume()) focus. enableForegroundDispatch() must be called from the main thread and only when the activity is in the foreground (calling in onResume() guarantees this)

```
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    nfcadapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
}

public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    nfcadapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, intentFiltersArray, techListsArray);
}

public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
    Tag tagFromIntent = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);
    //do something with tagFromIntent
}
```